# Is it possible to use Umbraco 5 to perform searches against another database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, umbraco

I'm so new to Umbraco it's not even funny.  I've built a few apps in house that are MVC3/razor so I'd prefer to use Umbraco 5.  Plus the "Hive" sounds like what I'm looking for.

So, please forgive my ignorance.
What I hope to do eventually one day is after I've built out the majority of my site in Umbraco, basic static content pages.  I'd like to integrate some how a page that users can enter search criteria and click submit, and it returns either multiple records, or a single detail page for the search performed.

The data is in another database, it is not possible to integrate into Umbraco.  I've read up on Surface controllers and it sounds like it's very possible to return data from another system to a template.  But is it possible to filter the data just like a regular web application?

Comment: What do you mean by "filter" the data? If you can connect to a database, query it and retrieve results, then you can also filter that data right?

Comment: In all the examples I've found from Umbraco customization the examples don't apply any clauses to the query. For instance. They have an action .GetAllArtists() I need to do .GetAllArtistsByName(string name) http://h4rdboiledegg.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/adventures-with-umbraco-5-part-5-surface-controller/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own *areas* and define *routes* and point those to customer *controllers* where you can query your database and do the stuff you'd like to do.

So you can entirely bypass Umbraco if that's what you want..

**Edit:**

You could always add a querystring which will be passed to controller actions as parameters.

Let's say: `domain.com/allartists` points to:

```
GetAllArtists()
```

Then you could call: `domain.com/allartists?name=Jackson` which would match:

```
GetAllArtists(string name)
```

Comment: Will this make the site layout defined in Umbraco apply automatically to my areas?  please link to any resources.  Umbraco5 is so new Documentation is sparse.